# EntityCommandExectuionException was unhandled by user during raw SQL execution

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on MVC application, where I am using entity framework for table generation etc. I am facing a challenge in joining two tables using Entity framework.

I have a dropdown in my view and listed all report types. My objective is to generate report for selected drop down in view. I will pass the selected id as parameter to controller, I need to fetch the fetch the corresponding query from the Report table from back and substitute in raw query. Currently I am trying it by hard coding the query(instead of fetching it from report table) but getting exception. Note for testing purpose I am not sending any parameter right now. I like to use only one report action to generate all my report for the selected value in the view.

Here is my code in the controller.

```
 public ActionResult GenerateReport()
            {
                var model = new ReportViewModel();
                using (var context = new FloorContext())
                {
                  //  var result = context.Employees.SqlQuery("SELECT * from Employees").ToList();
//Employee employee = context.Employees.FirstOrDefault(emp => emp.EmployeeId ==detail.EmployeeId);
                    var result2 = context.Database.SqlQuery<string>("SELECT e.EmployeeId, e.EntityId, e.EmployeeRefID,p.ProjectId from Employees e,Projectemployeemapping p where e.EmployeeId=p.EmployeeId").FirstOrDefault<string>();

                    foreach (var detail in result2)
                    {
                        Employee employee = context.Employees.FirstOrDefault(emp => emp.EmployeeId == detail.EmployeeId);

                        if (employee != null)
                            model.ReportDetails.Add(
                                new reportmodel
                                {
                                    Id = employee.EmployeeId,
                                    EmployeeName = employee.FirstName + " " + employee.LastName,
                                    Location = "",
                                    Project = ""

                                });
                    }
                }
                return PartialView(model);
            }
```

The below two query working as expected.

```
//  var result = context.Employees.SqlQuery("SELECT * from Employees").ToList();
//Employee employee = context.Employees.FirstOrDefault(emp => emp.EmployeeId ==detail.EmployeeId);
```

But I need to join two tables and return the result back to my view using raw SQL query.

I have referred to some of the sites, but I didn't get any answer for joining two tables. The below query

```
var result2 = context.Database.SqlQuery<string>("SELECT e.EmployeeId, e.EntityId, e.EmployeeRefID,p.ProjectId from Employees e,Projectemployeemapping p where e.EmployeeId=p.EmployeeId").FirstOrDefault<string>();

gives me the following error:
```

> EntityCommandExectuionException was unhandled by user.

The data reader has more than one field. Multiple fields are not valid for EDM primitive or enumeration types.

The Projectemployeemapping is created like this during run time, so I can't able to get the table name in the context.

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Project>()
                .HasMany(prj => prj.Employees)
                .WithMany(emp => emp.Projects)
                .Map(prj => prj.MapLeftKey("ProjectId").MapRightKey("EmployeeId").
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to Join table in entity framework using raw sql query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24351270/how-to-join-table-in-entity-framework-using-raw-sql-query)

Comment: i deleted the old and and added more info in this.